# Is calling a property's method from another method of the same object in this manner ok?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this, instance

Can someone help me understand why the code below works and if this is an acceptable pattern to use?

Without getting into it too much I have a basic state machine functionality inside an object called `states` in a simple browser game I am making and I able to trigger event transitions by calling `states.event('someEvent')` from within the states object itself. For instance if the update method of a given state, say `states.someState.actions.onUpdate()` is running it can call `states.event('someNewEvent')`. Doing it this way is not something I need to do, I did it accidentally but I was very confused by the fact that it worked. So the code below is that logic/functionality which I don't understand reduced down to a simple example.

I can't seen to find any information that would explain this type of pattern.
Everywhere online would seem to suggest that I write "this.printText()" instead of "myObj.printText()" but it only prints when I do it the way I have below.

This seems like it might be bad practice, at the very least it would be because I don't understand quite why it works... Any help would be appreciated. I struggle a lot with javascript coming from C# in unity game engine.

```
let myObj = {
  printText: function() {
    console.log('I thought this would not print');
  },
  myProperty: {
    toPrint: function () {
      myObj.printText();
    }
  }
  
}
myObj.myProperty.toPrint();
```

Comment: what the value of `this` is can be confusing when dealing with objects like you are

Comment: In your example, `myProperty` simply contains a plain object that has a `toPrint` method. That `toPrint` method refers to `myObj` via a closure, and that's why it works. If you used `this` instead of `myObj`, then `this` would be referring to the `myProperty` object when you called it as `myObj.myProperty.toPrint()` I think there are probably cases where nesting a method like you have in your example makes sense to do, but it would depend on the situation.

Comment: You're defining an object with functions and object nesting functions, there's nothing wrong with this practice as long as within this object we're not calling any of these object's items before declaration which would throw.